# Running dask map_partition functions in multiple workers

Tags: python, docker, dask, dask-distributed

I have a dask architecture implemented with five docker containers: a client, a scheduler, and three workers. I also have a large dask dataframe stored in parquet format in a docker volume. The dataframe was created with 3 partitions, so there are 3 files (one file per partition).

I need to run a function on the dataframe with `map_partitions`, where each worker will take one partition to process.

My attempt:

```
def my_function(dfx):
    return dfx['abc'] = dfx['def'] + 1

df = dd.read_parquet(... path to parquet file)

client = Client('127.0.0.1:8786')

with joblib.parallel_backend('dask'):
      df = df.map_partitions(my_function)
```

Is this the correct approach? how to tell dask to use the `client` variable in the `with` statement so the functions run on the workers? Do I need `df.compute()` to start the execution?

**Note: removing the 'with' statement, this works fine if the dask client is run on Jupyter. Problem is when the Dask client is run on Docker as Dask creates the workers in the web application instead of the Docker containers.**

**UPDATE**

docker compose file:

```
version: '3'

services:   

  web:
    image: img-python-01
    container_name: cont_flask
    volumes:
      - c:/visualcode-py:/code
      - c:/conf:/conf
      - vol_dask_data:/data
      - vol_dask_model:/model
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    working_dir: /code
    environment:
      - app.config=/conf/py.app.json
      - common.config=/conf/py.common.json 
      - CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=''
    entrypoint:
      - gunicorn
    command:
      - -t 7200
      - -b 0.0.0.0:5000
      - --reload
      - app.frontend.app:app
      
      
  scheduler:
    image: img-python-01
    container_name: cont_scheduler
    ports:
      - "8787:8787"
      - "8786:8786"
    entrypoint:
      - dask-scheduler

  worker:
    image: img-python-01
    depends_on:
      - scheduler
    environment:
      - app.config=/conf/py.app.json
      - common.config=/conf/py.common.json 
      - PYTHONPATH=/code
      - MODEL_PATH=/model/rfc_model.pkl
      - PREPROCESSING_PATH=/model/data_columns.pkl
      - SCHEDULER_ADDRESS=scheduler
      - SCHEDULER_PORT=8786
      - CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=''
    working_dir: /code
    volumes:
      - c:/visualcode-py:/code
      - c:/conf:/conf
      - c:/winfiles:/winfiles
      - vol_dask_data:/data
      - vol_dask_model:/model
    entrypoint:
      - dask-worker
    command:
      - scheduler:8786
    
volumes:
  vol_dask_data:
     name: vol_dask_data
  vol_dask_model:
     name: vol_dask_model
```

Starts with `docker-compose up -d --scale worker=4`, the flask/gunicorn application runs on `web`.

**Note: this configuration works fine when I run a `client.submit()`, workers run on containers.**

**UPDATE 2**

This is the code that works with current docker compose file:

```
futures1 = client.submit(process_loans, exec_id, 1, dataset, w1)
futures2 = client.submit(process_loans, exec_id, 2, dataset, w2)

worker_responses = client.gather([futures1, futures2])
```

I see in the Dask dashboard that the function `process_loans` is running on the worker containers

Comment: I think Dask would automatically use `client` here? And, you probably wouldn't even need to use joblib because `my_function` will act on the underlying pandas DataFrames? -- It'll also be helpful if you could share some details about what `my_function` will do :)

Comment: Added `my_function`. If I don't use the `with` statement how do you tell dask to use the workers?

Comment: When you create a `Client` object, Dask would automatically start using the ["distributed" scheduler](https://distributed.dask.org/en/stable/) for all computations, including Dask DataFrame operations like `map_partitions`. And, the distributed scheduler can manage tasks+workers appropriately, does that make sense? Please let me know if I'm missing something! I'd also encourage to try it yourself, and keep an eye on the Dashboard to make sure all workers are being used. :)

Comment: @pavithraes I removed `with joblib.parallel_backend('dask'):` but the function runs on the dask client, not on the worker, what could be wrong?

Comment: Interesting, could you please share some details about how have you [configured your cluster (scheduler + workers)](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/deploying.html)? -- I mean, are you using a cluster manager, or using the CLI tools, etc.?

Comment: I think I found the issue. If I run the dask client in Jupyter, it works as you said. But if I run the client in flask in a docker container, it doesn't work. I added to the question my docker compose file. Note that this docker configuration works fine when I do `client.submit` or `client.map`, maybe I need to do `client.map_partitions`?

Comment: I feel like everything might be working just fine because `client.submit` triggers execution on the workers... `client.submit` is executed _immediately_ (that's why you see activity on workers in the dashboard), whereas `map_partitions` would be evaluated _lazily_, i.e., only when you call `compute`. Could you please confirm if the following shows activity on your workers in the dashboard: After `client = Client('127.0.0.1:8786')
`, do `df = df.map_partitions(my_function).compute()` (no need for the `with` statement)?

Comment: I do realize you mentioned this works with Jupyter and not with Docker, but it'll still be super helpful if you can confirm the above. Thank you so much for being patient here :)  -- For context, I'm confused because `client.submit` is working as expected. And, `df.compute()` call would do `client.compute(df).result()`, i.e., internally it'll use a similar-ish workflow -- which is why it's odd to me that it doesn't work; and it'll be nice to have a clear confirmation and see any error messages you get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `python` snippet does not appear to use the `dask` API efficiently. It might be that your actual function is a bit more complex, so `map_partitions` cannot be avoided, but let's take a look at the simple case first:

```py
def my_function(dfx):
    # return dfx['abc'] = dfx['def'] + 1
    # the above returns the result of assignment
    # we need to separate the assignment and return statements
    dfx['abc'] = dfx['def'] + 1
    return dfx

df = dd.read_parquet(... path to parquet file)

client = Client('127.0.0.1:8786')

with joblib.parallel_backend('dask'):
      df = df.map_partitions(my_function)
```

Another way to re-write the above (for this basic case) is to explicitly assign new column values:

```py
df = dd.read_parquet(... path to parquet file)
df['abc'] = df['def'] + 1
```

Or to use the `.assign` method:

```py
df = (
    dd.read_parquet(path_to_parquet_file)
    .assign(abc=lambda df: df['def'] + 1)
)
```

In terms of the other questions:

- if a `client` is created outside the context, `joblib` will use the existing client;
- for restricting computations to one worker per partition, the easiest one is to assign each worker a specific unit of resource `foo` and require that each computation uses up one `foo` of the available resources, see [`docs on resources`](http://distributed.dask.org/en/stable/resources.html);
- whether `.compute` is necessary depends on what is happening downstream. If the data can fit into available memory and it is efficient to have data in memory, then `.compute` should be executed. Otherwise, it is likely to be more efficient to delay any actual computations until the final step. For example, if the end result of this code is saving of the updated data to another set of parquet files, then there is no need to issue `.compute` since `dask` will trigger computations when `.to_parquet` is executed.

Comment: you were spot on `if a client is created outside the context, joblib will use the existing client;` the entire code was submitted with `fire_and_forget` using `client = Client()` and apparently that was the client used by `map_partitions`. Changing `client = Client()` to `client = Client('127.0.0.1:8786')` in the `fire_and_forget` fixed the problem. Still, I would like to use BOTH the local and the docker clients, is that achievable?

Comment: In general, this is possible, especially if you use context managers to open/close the clients only for the needed parts. However, the cases where this might be necessary have to be special in some way... One possible work-around is to add the local machine to the cluster, e.g. [to avoid wasting a local GPU](https://github.com/dask/dask-jobqueue/issues/471#issuecomment-717405954).

Answer (score 3):

It seems to me that there is some confusion here between the various pieces of the system.

First let me point out that the function as given produces a syntax error. Maybe you meant

```
def my_function(dfx): 
    dfx['abc'] = dfx['def'] + 1
    return dfx
```

(this was mentioned in another answer)

Secondly, why is joblib involved at all here? You do not seem to be submitting work to joblib anywhere, it is not being used at all. All you need are dask API calls and your client.

```
df2 = df.map_partitions(my_function)
```

and then do whatever it is that you wanted to do with `df2`. This dos not yet begin any execution, it makes a graph of operations to be carried out.

If you wanted to resolve the whole resultant dataset into client memory (this is probably not what you wanted!), you could do

```
out = df2.compute()
```

and this will use your distributed scheduler automatically.
You could also be more explicit

```
f = client.compute(df2)
```

which returns a *future* that you can either wait on (`f.result()` and other functions in `distributed`) or allow to proceed in the background.

Comment: Thanks, this clarifies a lot, still the question was why the workers are running on the client docker container instead of the worker docker containers, even when not using joblib.